# link from html to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, href

In dynamic Web Project I have  - default.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Create new customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="\WEB-INF\forms\CustomerMenu.jsp">Test new</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also the CustomerMenu.jsp page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Create new customer</title>
</head>
<body>
    // Table ..
</body>
</html>
```

The pages hierarchy is as the snapshot  -

[image]

When I press on the link in default.html I get error message

```
- HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` folder are not publicly accessible without using a front controller [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) or a specific tag like `<jsp:include>` which does either a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) or [`RequestDispatcher#include()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).

If you need to access a JSP file *directly* by URL, then you should not be placing the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder. Put it outside the `/WEB-INF` folder

```
WebContent
 |-- forms
 |    |-- CreateNewCustomer.html
 |    |-- CustomerMenu.html
 |    `-- CustomerMenu.jsp
 |-- WEB-INF
 :    :
```

and fix the link accordingly.

```html
<a href="forms/CustomerMenu.jsp">Test new</a>
```

Comment: just an emphesis of BalusC says, the /WEB-INF folder if a protected one as part of a web container and it's why all web assets -images, css, js, ...- aren't included within.

Comment: @BalusC  , the the folder in WebContent must called "forms" ?

Comment: No. It was just how *you* originally called it. I just untouched it. All I did was moving the folder to the right place. You can name/structure it whatever you want as long as it's publicly accessible. You can even get rid of it altogether and just put its files straight in the root folder (the `WebContent` folder, there where the `default.html` file is also sitting in).

Answer (score 3):

`WEB-INF` folder is not accessible outside. 
You will either need to move the jsp outside of `WEB-INF` or use forward request to forward to the jsp.