# how to change url by RESTful URL mapping in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm trying to do RESTful URL mapping

this works like when i enter value of url tag curriculum/board, it goes to path of 
 /curriculum1.4/controller.jspx

```
<url method="GET" value="curriculum/board">/curriculum1.4/controller.jspx</url>
<url method="GET" value="curriculum/board/write">/curriculum1.4/write_view.jsp</url>
```

now I want to change the path on myscript.js. also  jquery doesn't work on this path curriculum/board i don't know why.. it's still same jsp file but why it doesn't work?

myscript.js

```
function writeClick() {
    window.location.href = "write_view.jsp";
}
function listClick() {
    window.location.href = "controller.jspx";
}
```

I tried like this but it didn't work. how should i change the path?

```
function writeClick() {
        window.location.href = "curriculum/board/write";
    }
    function listClick() {
        window.location.href = "/curriculum/board";
    }
```

list.jsp

```
<td colspan="5"><button onclick="writeClick();">write</button>

<input  type="button" value="list" onclick="listClick()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope both the urls using GET mapping. Try to hit the jsp in the browser like

```
http://localhost:8080/curriculum1.4/controller.jspx
http://localhost:8080/curriculum1.4/write_view.jsp
```

Note: change the port number (8080).

If you find out the full link, then replace the value in window.location.href.

Links to try:

```
http://localhost:{your_port_number}/{project_name}/curriculum1.4/controller.jspx
http://localhost:{your_port_number}/{project_name}/{package_name}/curriculum1.4/controller.jspx
http://localhost:{your_port_number}/{project_name}/{resource_folder_name}/curriculum1.4/controller.jspx
```

Still you can't find url?
check the following links.

[web project file locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050624/6650476)

[Link for jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779775/6650476)

Try using servlet. I guess that is the good programming.